# How to assign second integer to a pointer value?

Tags: c++, queue

I am working on a Customer Queue problem where customers arrive at the store and form
a queue. Each customer places an order that takes anywhere between 1 and 6 minutes to fulfill.

I am stuck trying to figure out how to assign the order time to the customer. For example, if a customer arrived at 8:00AM and had an order time of 4 minutes, how would I connect that value to the customer Queue.

I thought of two possible solutions but am not sure how to go about it:

#1: Pointing to an array (if that is even possible) -> [in_time, order_time]

#2: Chain pointers such that for each time the customer arrives, there is an additional pointer with the order_time value.

I currently have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;


class Customer {
    public:
        int in_time;
        int out_time;
        int order_time;
    Customer *next;
    Customer() {
        next = NULL;

    }

};

class Queue {
    public:
    Customer *head, *tail;
    Queue() {
        head = NULL;
    }

    void enqueue(int TIME, int generator) {
        Customer *temp = new Customer;
        Customer *order = new Customer;
        temp->in_time = TIME;
        order->order_time = generator;
        
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = temp;
        }
        else {
           temp->next = head;
           head = temp; 

        }

    };
```

My main() function

```
int main() {

    Queue Q;
    int TIME = 0, generator, in_time;

    while (TIME < 1020) {
        //1, should we add a new customer to the Q at this minute?
        if (TIME >= 0 && TIME <= 120) {
            //8AM to 10AM
            generator = rand()%100 + 1; //1 to 100
            if (generator <=30) {
                generator = rand()%6 +1;
                cout << "new customer arrived at time: " << TIME << " with order time: " << generator << endl;

                Q.enqueue(TIME, generator); // add this person to Q. do this for all other time slots
            }
        }
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: I feel like this is an XY problem... What is the point of creating a custom Queue class? Also, can you post the code for class Customer?

Comment: First, where is a container that is used by your Queue class? Second, why you use Queue class at all, what is it's purpose? Third, why not to use simple std::queue instead? Fourth, why not to make an order a member value of customer class? And atlast, If a customer object is not used anywhere else except the queue itself, is it really needed to store pointers?

Comment: @Alexey i just added additional code at the top. Using a custom Queue class is something we've been learning in our data and algorithm class so that was my go-to.

Comment: After edit, one more question - why a customer class should store a pointer to the next customer? You have a bad design

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer:

```
    void enqueue(int TIME, int generator) {
        Customer *temp = new Customer;
        temp->in_time = TIME;
        temp->order_time = generator;
        
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = temp;
        }
        else {
           temp->next = head;
           head = temp; 

        }

    };
```

I misunderstood how pointers worked and added a new pointer called order which was completely unnecessary since I already created a pointer called temp.